# Vector and interface polymorphism

Tags: java, vector, interface, polymorphism

So in a cellphone company I have few vectors of different class types, lets say:

```
Vector<Employee>
Vector<Customer>
Vector<Device>
```

I also have few interfaces that some of the classes implements. So I want to make a static function in the main class that will update a given "Updateable" vector. it could be customer or employee, any vector which it's types can be Updateable (implements the same interface).
I did this:

```
public static int updateRates(Vector v) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) {
        if (((Update)v.get(i)).update() == true)
            sum++;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

That works, but I want to avoid the use of casting.. is there any way to apply this by any polymorphism way?

Comment: So `updateRates` should take any `Vector<? extends Update>` and `Employee`, `Customer` and `Device` all implement `Update`?

Comment: it will recieve any vector that its type implements Updateable. thus it will run over the vector elements and return how many types were updated.

Comment: Then [rafalopez79' answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27580864/1392132) should do the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make an interface Updateable

```
public interface Updateable{
   boolean isUpdated();
}
```

Change the classes Employee, Device, Customer implement the Updateable inteface.

Change the vector you pass to the static method to

```
Vector <? extends Updateable> 


public static int updateRates(Vector<? extends Updateable>  v) {
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) {
    if (v.get(i).isUpdated()){
        sum++;
    }
}
return sum;
}
```

Comment: There is no need to change the vector.  In fact, I recommend against doing so.  The wildcard will accept any `Vector<T>` where `T instanceof Updateable`.  You can pass in a `Vector<Employe>` without any further ado.

Comment: Thank you both! I changed the argument as suggested by rafalopez79 but didn't change the vector type. it all works perfectly!